# Chrome Extension Manifest issues with web_accessible_resources (Blocked)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

Here's the manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "JRBot Viz Extension",
  "description": "This extension will listen to a tab, then open the visualizer for the audio from that tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["popup.js", "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"]
    },
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["resources/*"],
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "http://*.google.com/",
   "https://*.googleapis.com/"
   ]
}
```

Here's the script executed on clicking a button from the extension popup:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('vizualizePage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "addViz.js"});

    });

  }, false);
}, false);
```

And here's the `addViz.js` script that's executed:

```
d = document;     
var extUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("");

$('body').prepend('<div id="viz-div" style="background-color: #000; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 100000;"></div>');
$('#viz-div').load(extUrl + 'resources/audio-circle.html');
```

So, Everything acts as expected up until it's supposed to load `resources/audio-circle.html`.

The console says: 
`Denying load of chrome-extension://[EXTENSION ID]/resources/audio-circle.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.`

As you can see, the resource folder IS declared as web accessible in the manifest, I've confirmed the location is correct by opening the referenced url in a new tab and the HTML document appears.

I've tried declaring the one file by itself and removing the wildcard but that didn't change anything.

I've also tried placing the resource in the extension root but still the same thing.

I've exhausted all the resources I can find on the internet regarding proper usage for `web_accessible_resource` (There's not much), but I still can't find a solution.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Did you reload your extension after modifying manifest.json? If not, do that and the issue will go away.

Comment: Yes. It's the first thing I've done each time and the error message reflects any changes I've made to the pathing etc...

Comment: Any solution ? Its happening with me also

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the project no longer exists and even if a correct answer is given, it can no longer be verified as correct. This appears to be been specific to my project and my environment.

Answer (score -1):

Closing and reopening Chrome fixed it for me

Comment: This is a very old question, for versions of  chrome and libraries that are no longer in use. How exactly is your answer useful to anyone else with a similar issue? What issue was resolved for you? How is your issue related to this one?

Comment: @JRadtheBad Since this issue exactly still happens and has happened to me - which is how I got to this question to begin with. It resolved exactly what was mentioned in the question. Downvote all you want but if someone might find it helpful and save him some time I'm good with that.